# Calculate a datetime difference as a decimal in hours in Pandasql

Tags: python, sql, sqldf, pandasql

I want the difference of a datetime type column(date) as a decimal in hours .(0.001,0.2,etc)
I tried using SQL query using sqldf of pandasql library,but I can see only 0 as output.
Code I tried is :

```
    temp="""select 
id1,id2,(max(date)- 
 min(date))/3600 as hours from df 
 group by 1,2"""
 Dfhours=ps.sqldf(temp,locals())
```

id is if type int64 and date is of type datetime64[ns] .I also tried using DATADIFF but not helping

Comment: What do you mean with as a decimal in hours? So if there's 3 days, 8 hours, 30 minutes and 0 seconds of difference, you want 3*24+8+0,5 = 80,5 as output?

Comment: I want the answer In hours basically

Comment: Can you get the output of your query into a dataframe and share it? With that information I should be able to help you out please.

Comment: Basically for hours column I'm getting only 0 for all the rows

Comment: What I meant is, I'd rather get the select query into a dataframe (share it with us please) and then solve the issue using pandas.